# When the mouse buttons are swapped in the OS, do the mouse click event handlers still work correctly with respect to which button was clicked?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, mouseevent

Working in IT, I occasionally encounter users who are left-handed and prefer to use the mouse with their left hand, and often they switch the mouse buttons so the right button becomes the "primary" instead of the left button.

Here's what this configuration looks like in Windows:

[image]

How does this affect .NET applications (e.g. WPF, Winforms, etc.) which have code that relies on specific mouse buttons?

With the WPF [PreviewMouseDown event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmousedown(v=vs.110).aspx), for example, [MouseButtonEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebuttoneventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) has a [ChangedButton property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebuttoneventargs.changedbutton(v=vs.110).aspx) which yields a [MouseButton enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebutton(v=vs.110).aspx) value.  The description for `Left` is "The left mouse button."  There is nothing said about "primary" or "secondary" buttons.

Similarly for the Winforms [MouseClick event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick(v=vs.110).aspx), there is [MouseEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) with its [Button property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.button(v=vs.110).aspx) yielding a [MouseButtons enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mousebuttons(v=vs.110).aspx); the description for `Left` is simply "The left mouse button was pressed.", and again there is no mention of "standard" or "secondary" buttons.

In fact, all of the documentation I've seen related to the mouse and its buttons simply refer to the buttons by their location on a standard mouse setup.  None of the documentation refers to "primary" or "secondary" mouse buttons.

Does the .NET framework adapt appropriately to changes in the OS' button configuration?  Or will the following WPF and Winforms code break?

#### WPF:

```
void MainWindow_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
    {
        // do something where the "standard" mouse 
        // button must be the one that was clicked.
    }
}
```

#### Winforms:

```
private void MainForm_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        // do something where the "standard" mouse 
        // button must be the one that was clicked.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By running a couple tests, I've determined that .NET *is* smart enough to recognize that the buttons have been swapped.

For instance, in both of the following tests with WPF and Winforms, after switching the mouse buttons in Windows, I clicked the physical "right" mouse button, but **the event responded by indicating that the "left" mouse button was used**:

#### WPF:

[image]

#### Winforms:

[image]

Therefore, despite the lack of documentation by Microsoft, `Left` actually refers to the "standard" mouse button and `Right` refers to the "secondary" mouse button.

Comment: These results probably stem from the messages being propagated to each window by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to know if mouse is configured for left or right hand.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int nIndex);
```

...

```
int swapButton = GetSystemMetrics(23);
if (swapButton != 0)
{
     MessageBox.Show("left-handed");
}
else
{
     MessageBox.Show("right-handed");
}
```